# How to split a list based on new line in the list

Tags: python, list

I've list like this.

```
list =    ['As Michael Harvey writes, paragraphs are “in essence—a form of punctuation, and like other former. ',
     '',
     'Many novice writers tend to make a sharp distinction between content and style, thinking that a paper can be strong']
```

As we can observer there is an empty list ''. I want to split my list based on the empty list.

**Expected output:**

#input

```
input_list = ['some text ', '', 'some texts example']
```

Output:

```
list1 = ['some text ']
list2 = ['some text example']
```

Comment: Does it need to scale to x output lists ?

Comment: Do you need the output as a list of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go over each element in the list en remove it when there is an element with length 0.

```
l =    ['As Michael Harvey writes, paragraphs are “in essence—a form of punctuation, and like other former. ',
     '',
     'Many novice writers tend to make a sharp distinction between content and style, thinking that a paper can be strong']

output = [ele for ele in l if len(ele) > 0]
list1, list2 = output
```

This works for your example, but it does not "split" on the empty element.  Then you can use a for loop:

```
output = ['']

for ele in l:
    if len(ele) > 0:
        output[-1] += ele
    else:
        output.append('')
```

This last part *splits* your list:

```
l = ['a', 'b', '', 'c']
output = ['']

for ele in l:
    if len(ele) > 0:
        output[-1] += ele
    else:
        output.append('')
# output = ['ab', 'c']
```

Edit: output as lists:

```
l = ['a', 'b', '', 'c']
output = [[]]

for ele in l:
    if len(ele) > 0:
        output[-1].append(ele)
    else:
        output.append([])
# output = [['a', 'b'], ['c']]
```

If you have more lists it stops here since output can be as large as you want. If you know the result is two lists you can unpack them:

```
lst1, lst2 = output
```

*sidenote: do not use variable `list` since it is a data structure in python.*

Comment: That was nice explanation. As I mentioned in my question. The output should be list. But, In your case output is "str"

Comment: I'll edit my answer for you, but if you understand the principle, maybe you can try it yourself, see it as a learning way for the next problem you want to tackle with python and lists.

Answer (score 1):

Super basic solution. Allows for splitting of more than two sentences. Output in *sentences* variable, a list of lists.

```
list = ['a','','b','','c']
sentences = []
for s in list:
    if len(s)!=0:
        sentences.append([s])
```

There are better and faster solutions in other answers here, this one just details a not-so-technical/beginner friendly solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many lists you are going to have:

```
list1, *list2 = (i for i in input_list if i)
```

otherwise, in case you do not know how many lists you are going to end up with, you will probably end up with a `dict` or a `list` of `list`'s

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary of lists.

```
l =    ['As Michael Harvey writes, paragraphs are “in essence—a form of punctuation, and like other former. ',
     '',
     'Many novice writers tend to make a sharp distinction between content and style, thinking that a paper can be strong']

lists = dict()
x = 1
for ele in l:
  if(len(ele) > 0): # checking if the length of the element in l is sufficient (larger than 0)
    lists[x] = [ele] # adding a list with the element to the dictionary
    x += 1
```

Output:

> lists[1] = ['As Michael Harvey writes, paragraphs are “in essence—a
> form of punctuation, and like other former. ']
>
> lists[2] = ['Many novice writers tend to make a sharp distinction
> between content and style, thinking that a paper can be strong']

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below-attached snippet for that.

```
list =    ['As Michael Harvey writes, paragraphs are “in essence—a form of punctuation, and like other former. ',
     '',
     'Many novice writers tend to make a sharp distinction between content and style, thinking that a paper can be strong']

out = [[i] for i in list if i!='']

# Printing each list
for i in out:
  print(i)
```

[image: Output of the above code]

[Run the code here](https://replit.com/@ravitejagullapudi/split-a-list-based-on-new-line-in-the-list#main.py)